# Application crashes because of the Fragment? Error Inflating Class Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I used a Navigation drawer application/project. I just followed what I did in a tutorial (they just used a simple project not using a Navigation Drawer) but when I tried implementing it in a Navigation Drawer it crashes. I don't know why it crashes but I think it's about the fragment.

What I want to happen is: Show the fragment at start of the application and that's why I used the 'content_main.xml' in the Navigation Drawer(Am I right? That's the one that shows the start-up content when you run the application?).

My MainActivity codes in 'onCreate' method:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }
```

My searchFragment codes:

```
package rjj.sampleproject;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;


import com.weiwangcn.betterspinner.library.material.MaterialBetterSpinner;

public class searchFragment extends Fragment {
    private searcher searcherImplementer;
    public interface searcher{
        public void searchForRoutesCategory(String route, String category);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        this.searcherImplementer =(searcher)context;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_search_category, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        Button flightSearchButton = (Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button2);
        flightSearchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MaterialBetterSpinner route = (MaterialBetterSpinner)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.spinner_routes);
                MaterialBetterSpinner category = (MaterialBetterSpinner)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.spinner_category);

                searcherImplementer.searchForRoutesCategory(route.getText().toString(),category.getText().toString());


            }
        });
    }
}
```

My content_main.xml codes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="rjj.sampleproject.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:name="rjj.sampleproject.searchFragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

My activity_search_category.xml codes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <com.weiwangcn.betterspinner.library.material.MaterialBetterSpinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_category"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:hint="Select Category"
        />
    <com.weiwangcn.betterspinner.library.material.MaterialBetterSpinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_routes"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/spinner_category"
        android:hint="Select Routes"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:onClick="search"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner_routes"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/showAllRoutes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:text="Show All Routes"
        android:onClick="showAllRoutes"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The error that I am receiving:

```
08-19 15:04:45.281 3388-3394/? E/jdwp: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
08-19 15:04:45.351 3388-3388/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
08-19 15:04:45.471 3388-3388/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 3388: eglSurfaceAttrib(1199): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
08-19 15:04:45.531 3388-3388/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: rjj.sampleproject, PID: 3388
                                                 java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                     at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.performFiltering(AutoCompleteTextView.java:858)
                                                     at com.weiwangcn.betterspinner.library.material.MaterialBetterSpinner.onFocusChanged(MaterialBetterSpinner.java:49)
                                                     at android.view.View.handleFocusGainInternal(View.java:4617)
                                                     at android.view.View.requestFocusNoSearch(View.java:6999)
                                                     at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:6978)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:2414)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:2370)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:2414)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:2370)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:2414)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:2370)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:2414)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:2373)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:2414)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:2370)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:2414)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:2370)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:2414)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:2370)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:2414)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:2370)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.onRequestFocusInDescendants(ViewGroup.java:2414)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.requestFocus(ViewGroup.java:2373)
                                                     at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:6945)
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1828)
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

MaterialBetterSpinner.java codes:

```
package com.weiwangcn.betterspinner.library.material;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;

import com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialAutoCompleteTextView;

import java.util.Calendar;


public class MaterialBetterSpinner extends MaterialAutoCompleteTextView implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    private static final int MAX_CLICK_DURATION = 200;
    private long startClickTime;
    private boolean isPopup;

    public MaterialBetterSpinner(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    public MaterialBetterSpinner(Context arg0, AttributeSet arg1) {
        super(arg0, arg1);
        setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    public MaterialBetterSpinner(Context arg0, AttributeSet arg1, int arg2) {
        super(arg0, arg1, arg2);
        setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean enoughToFilter() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFocusChanged(boolean focused, int direction,
                                  Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {
        super.onFocusChanged(focused, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);
        if (focused) {
            performFiltering("", 0);
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getWindowToken(), 0);
            setKeyListener(null);
            dismissDropDown();
        } else {
            isPopup = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                startClickTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                long clickDuration = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() - startClickTime;
                if (clickDuration < MAX_CLICK_DURATION) {
                    if (isPopup) {
                        dismissDropDown();
                        isPopup = false;
                    } else {
                        requestFocus();
                        showDropDown();
                        isPopup = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        isPopup = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(Drawable left, Drawable top, Drawable right, Drawable bottom) {
        Drawable dropdownIcon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.ic_expand_more_black_18dp);
        if (dropdownIcon != null) {
            right = dropdownIcon;
            right.mutate().setAlpha(66);
        }
        super.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `MainActivity` should implements `searchFragment.searcher` and **override** the `searchForRoutesCategory` method

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener
                  ,searchFragment.searcher {
//                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

otherwise you trying to find `searcher` from activity which is not there

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    this.searcherImplementer =(searcher)context;
    // crash , searcher not implemented by Activity  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

Update : From [Repository docs](https://github.com/Lesilva/BetterSpinner), you need to setup an adapter and bind it with your `MaterialBetterSpinner`

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                 android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, COUNTRIES);
         BetterSpinner textView = (BetterSpinner)
                 findViewById(R.id.countries_list);
         textView.setAdapter(adapter);
     }

     private static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] {
         "Belgium", "France", "Italy", "Germany", "Spain"
     };
```

so you need to initialize them inside `onCreateView` and they are part of your fragment layout not Activity's so `(MaterialBetterSpinner)getActivity().` is incorrect

Comment: try to clean your project with suggest changes and see is `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: rjj.sampleproject.MainActivity cannot be cast to rjj.sampleproject.searchFragment$searcher` is still there in logs

Comment: Updated my crash details. Thank you.

Comment: now the error is in `MaterialBetterSpinner` at line 49 so post the code of `MaterialBetterSpinner.java`

Comment: It is a dependecy (I don't know what it is called) but you have to add it in the "build.gradle"  compile 'com.weiwangcn.betterspinner:library-material:1.1.0' I just got it from the internet. I have no codes for the materialBetterSpinner.java

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

There you go :

Here is your fragment file modified as per my coding:

```
public class SearchFragment extends Fragment {
    private searcher searcherImplementer;
    private View mView;
    private MaterialBetterSpinner route, category;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        this.searcherImplementer = (searcher) context;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (mView == null) {
            mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_search_category, container, false);
        }
        String[] list = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.month);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, list);
        category = (MaterialBetterSpinner) mView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_category);
        route = (MaterialBetterSpinner) mView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_routes);

        route.setAdapter(adapter);
        category.setAdapter(adapter);

        Button flightSearchButton = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        flightSearchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                searcherImplementer.searchForRoutesCategory(route.getText().toString(), category.getText().toString());
            }
        });
        return mView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    }
}
```

I think the only mistake you are doing is not setting adapter to any of your MaterialBetterSpinner. Hope this works for you :-) Give it a try. Let me know if you still face any issue.

**OLD**

Try to add fragment runtime something like this:

Your content_main.xml would be something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/llMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then from your activity add fragment like this:

```
    searchFragment fragment = new searchFragment();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out, R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frame,fragment, fragment.getClass().getName());
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: Are you still facing issue? At which line and which class it throws exception? If it is a nullpointerException on your autoCompleteTextview then there may be issue in your filtered data which is processed by AutoCompleteTextview on performFilter method. Some variable remains uninitialized or something like that. Please check it once.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem I am facing right now. It seems that it crashes because of that. I really don't know hwat to do to fix that.

Comment: Let me check further

Comment: 'com.weiwangcn.betterspinner:library-material:1.1.0' this is the dependency that I used that I got from the internet

Comment: Yes I found that

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to display the fragment and fixed the error by adding an adapter inside the searchFragment.java class.

The codes are:

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, ROUTES);
        MaterialBetterSpinner betterSpinner = (MaterialBetterSpinner)view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_routes);
        betterSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```